# Why the reducer variable cannot be access?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my first time using typescript to build a react app:

Here is my code:

```
import { useReducer } from "react";

let reducer = (state: any, action: any): object => {
    let result = { ...state };
    .............
    return result;
}
const initialState = { loading: true };

export default function TestWebRTC() {
    const [itemList, updateItemList] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    return (
        <div>
            {itemList.loading}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The error message is:

`Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'object'.`

The error statement is:

```
{itemList.loading}
```

Would you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Your reducer claims the return type is `object` which means the result of `useReducer` would be assumed to be the same. Since there is nothing to guarantee `loading` would be in the result, then TS rightfully tells you that it's unsafe. If you just use proper types, then you'd get the type safety and no warnings. It's really useless to have something like `(state: any, action: any): object` in TS as you're basically discarding all the benefits of TS and just deliberately trying to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: So, do you mean I need to create a type for the reducer state?

Comment: Or at least use `{ loading: boolean; }` instead of `object` as type declaration

Comment: Your effort is appreciated.